# Checking for strict mode compatibility in Javascript before invoking it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, strict

I am curious if there is anything wrong with the following code meant to test for Javascript strict mode compatibility before invoking it:

```
(function() { "use strict"; return this; })() || "use strict";
```

I'm worried it is either too bulky or won't actually work for some reason.

**Update**

Robert answer my question below very well. I thought I would put this here for future reference for other's benefit. From John Resig's "[ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode, JSON, and More](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)":

> [T]he syntax that’s used to enable strict mode...[is] simply a string in a single statement that happens to contain the contents “use strict”. No new syntax is introduced in order to enable strict mode. This is huge. This means that you can turn strict mode on in your scripts – today – and it’ll have, at worst, no side effect in old browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check won't work, and isn't needed. If the browser doesn't support strict mode, it'll simply treat the strict mode declaration as a string literal expression, which is a completely valid expression and has no side effects.

Just use the declaration directly when strict mode is desired in those browsers that support it.

In any case, the strict mode declaration is required to stand on its own, and not be part of a larger expression, otherwise even modern browsers that have strict mode support will see it as a common meaningless string literal.

Comment: I didn't know that the strict mode directive had to stand on its own. That's helpful. Thanks!